# Recaptcha scores very low in production

Tags: firebase, next.js, recaptcha, vercel, firebase-app-check

We have been using recaptcha for a while and everything has been good. Getting scores of 0.7 and above all of a sudden recently the scores started getting low. We use vercel and the preview urls are good even the given production urls by vercel the scores are good, 0.7 and above. But for the main domain url the score is 0.7 on first interaction then 0.3 from there.

We have the firebase appcheck integration in place in addition to Recaptcha but this should not be a problem since the implementation has been working correctly.

How can I resolve this since the only solution right now is to disable recaptcha to avoid affecting production users with this low scores.